# foreach loops in pure js, checking for matches

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm generating several hidden input fields like:

```
<input class="activeList" type="hidden" value="foobar-value"/>
```

Afterwards I'm doing stuff with Angular, but Angular isn't accepting jQuery. So it should be in Javascript. That's where I get stuck..

I wanna check of the following html matches with the input hidden field:

```
 <p class="foobar">value</p>
```

In the code underneath I already did some transformation from jQuery to pure JS.

If the text inside the foobar-paragraph matches the second part of the hidden input field, then it should add a class.

```
var activeList = [];
activeList.push(document.getElementsByClassName('activeList'));

activeList.forEach(function(entry) 
{    
    var string = entry.split(','); // gives an array of: [foobar,value];

    $('.'+string[0]).each(function()
    {
        if($(this).text() == string[1])
        {
            $(this).addClass('yes'); 
            // makes: .foobar.yes
        }
    });

    if (document.getElementsByClassName(string[0]).length){ 
        /// this is the farest i get.   
    }
});
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: You should be using `ng-model` to access the input value.

Comment: Have you added a reference to pure.js?

Answer (score 5):

There are problems with your code:

- `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList object, when you push it to an array and use forEach, there is only **1 loop** and your `entry` object in the callback function is the NodeList object which does not have `split` method.
- To access hidden field value, you need to access `value` property of the DOM
- Use `split('-')` instead of `split(',')`

Try:

```
var activeList = document.getElementsByClassName('activeList');//document.getElementsByClassName returns a NodeList

for (i=0;i<activeList.length;i++)
{    
    var string = activeList[i].value.split('-'); // you have to access the value attribute and change , to -

    $('.'+string[0]).each(function()
    {
        if($(this).text() == string[1])
        {
            $(this).addClass('yes'); 
            // makes: .foobar.yes
        }
    });

    if (document.getElementsByClassName(string[0]).length){ 
        /// this is the farest i get.   
    }
};
```

If you want to use `forEach`, you need to convert the NodeList to array using `Array.prototype.slice.call`. For example:

```
var activeList = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('activeList'));

activeList.forEach(function(entry)
    {    
        var string = entry.value.split('-'); // you have to access the value attribute and change , to -

        $('.'+string[0]).each(function()
        {
            if($(this).text() == string[1])
            {
                $(this).addClass('yes'); 
                // makes: .foobar.yes
            }
        });

        if (document.getElementsByClassName(string[0]).length){ 
            /// this is the farest i get.   
        }
  });
```

Another solution is using `Array.prototype.forEach.call`.

```
var activeList = document.getElementsByClassName('activeList');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(activeList ,function(entry){    
   //Your code just like above
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pAg9B/)

Comment: Helpful, thanks. But I also wanna remove the jQuery stuff, because I can't access the jQuery - it's a Angular project.

Comment: Edit: ```TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'forEach'``` for both.

Comment: @user3233979: about removing jQuery, it's not necessary, we could use both jQuery and Angular